# Make AEM MemoryUsage parameters a part of the code base

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, aem-6

I would like to set the `Automatic Heap Dump Threshold (%)` and `Automatic Heap Dump Interval (s)` in the `Memory Usage` console (http://localhost:4502/system/console/memoryusage) paremeters for my AEM instance but I want to set these parameters from my codebase/source code. Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to expose an OSGi configuration, though if you take a look at the network panel, you can see the POST request that is executed to set the value, so, maybe at least you can have a script to set the values for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is done through configuration not code actually as this is a part of AEM configuration.

You can either:

1. Add the below details in start.bat/start.sh file of AEM:

`CQ_JVM_OPTS='-server –Xms8192m –Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M`

where as

```
Xms is Min heap - size can be increased depending on the your instance RAM size
Xmx is Max heap - size can be increased depending on the your instance RAM size
MaxPermSize size can be increased depending on the your instance RAM size
```

2. You can also add the same as command line arguments when starting your local server through command line
   `–Xms8192m –Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M`